# How to get the DOM element for a Sencha Touch draw component

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Ext.dom.Element has a setStyle method

I have a Ext.Component of xtype: 'draw'

When I use the inspector, I can set a background image under the canvas and then draw over the top of it.

What I can't find is a way to get the dome element so I can set the background property of the draw component.

I've tried:

```
var x = Ext.getCmp('mypanel');
x.setStyle('background', 'url(...)');           // No error, but no effect

var y = Ext.getCmp('mypanel').down('draw');
y.setStyle('background', 'url(...)');           // No error, but no effect
```

Given the Ext.component, how do I get the DOM element object so I can call the right setStyle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it:

```
var y = Ext.getCmp('mypanel').down('draw');
Ext.get(y.element).setStyle('background', 'url(...)')
```